# How to store data from Android to some cloud and access it from Windows 8 app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, azure-storage, google-cloud-storage, windows

I am making some App in android where I need to store images/videos on some cloud and I need view/retrieve that data in my windows 8 (Dextop) App. Which Cloud Service will be better to use and which I can use for Free (I need at max 1 GB)

Comment: you should also check out amazon web services

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/05/08/aws-free-usage-tier-now-includes-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 1):

App Engine with Google Cloud Storage. Perfect for that use.

Comment: Can you please share some tutorials about using App engine with C# ?

Comment: Currently, Google App Engine supports Java, Python, PHP, and Go.